Spark EOF Error (Parquet Read from S3)- Spark to Pandas conversion
I am reading close to 1 million rows stored in S3 as parquet files into a dataframe (900 MB size data in a bucket). Filtering the dataframe  based on values and then later converting to a Pandas dataframe . There are 2 UDFs involved (classify and transformDate). I am getting this error eof while running this code snippet. What is wrong with this code? Is it some spark setting that I am missing, or is it the improper use of UDF?
Code snippet below:
#Import headers skipped for simplicity

findspark.init()

#Simple Function to classify values
def classify(value):
    if float(value) < 0.0 or float(value) >= 10.0:
        return -1
    return int(float(value) * 2) + 1


#Simple Function to transform a string to date object
def transformDate(dateStr):
    date_format = '%d-%b-%Y:%H:%M:%S %Z'
    datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime("{} {}".format(dateStr, 'UTC'), date_format)
    return datetime_obj

def read_from_s3():
    conf = SparkConf()
    conf.set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4')
    conf.set('fs.s3a.impl', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem')
    conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum', 100)
    conf.set('fs.s3a.threads.max', 50)
    conf.set('spark.default.parallelism', 2048)
    conf.set('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions',4096)
    conf.set('spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled', 'true')
    conf.set('spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference','true')

    conf.set('spark.rpc.message.maxSize', '1024')
    conf.set('spark.executor.memory', '32g')
    conf.set('spark.shuffle.file.buffer', '64k')
    conf.set('spark.eventLog.buffer.kb', '200k')
    conf.set('spark.executor.cores', '8')
    conf.set('spark.cores.max', '8')
    conf.set('spark.driver.memory', '32g')
    conf.set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '21G')
    conf.set('spark.worker.cleanup.enabled', True)
    conf.set('spark.executor.heartbeatInterval', '43200s')
    conf.set('spark.network.timeout', '3000000s')


    conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', '<<>>')
    conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', '<<>>')
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('DEBUG')
    classify_udf = udf(lambda x:classify(x),IntegerType())
    transform_date_udf = udf(lambda x:transformDate(x),TimestampType())
    paths = 's3a://<<mybucket>>/'
    df = spark.read.parquet(paths,
        inferSchema=True)
    #Encode a col -colA which is in string format and create an integer representation for it
    df = df.withColumn('colA_encoded',classify_udf('colA'))
    #Encode a date string -str_date which is in string format and create timestamp with timezone
    df = df.withColumn('date_transformed',transform_date_udf('str_date'))
    return df


#Filter rows which have colA > 3.0 and retain all rows where colZ is present in this filtered data set (colA > 3.0)
#Basically keep all rows whose colZ has atleast one row with colA  > 3.0 
def do_filter(df: DataFrame):
    df = df.fillna({'colA':'0'})
    df= df.withColumn('colA_float',df['colA'].cast("float").alias('colA_float'))
    df2 = (df.filter(col('colA_float') > 3.0).select('colZ').distinct())
    df=df.join(df2, 'colZ')
    return df


#Function to group the dataframe by colZ and create index over colA
def do_proper_group(df: DataFrame):
    window = Window.partitionBy('colZ').orderBy('colA')
    df =df.select('*', dense_rank().over(window).alias('myIdx'))
    return df

def plot_data_frame(df: DataFrame =None) :
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    print(df.count())
    pandas_df = df.toPandas()
    print(pandas_df.columns)
    pandas_df.set_index('myIdx', inplace=True)
    pandas_df.groupby('colZ')['colA_float'].plot(legend=True,x='myIdx', xlabel="My Group Number", ylabel="Value")
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    print(start)
    plot_data_frame(do_proper_group(do_filter(read_from_s3())))
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)

Error log below:
24/07/24 06:47:31 DEBUG PythonUDFRunner: Exception thrown after task interruption
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Downloads\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 1225, in main
  File "D:\Downloads\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 596, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:572)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BasePythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BasePythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(generated.java:28)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
24/07/24 06:47:31 DEBUG Invoker: Starting: read
24/07/24 06:47:31 DEBUG PythonUDFRunner: Exception thrown after task interruption
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Downloads\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 1225, in main
  File "D:\Downloads\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 596, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:572)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BasePythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BasePythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(generated.java:28)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
24/07/24 06:47:31 DEBUG Invoker: Starting: lazySeek


Where is this EOF error coming from? Total of 760 files in S3 bucket with size totalling 900 M. All parquet files.
I'm not sure if the problem is centered around the Spark configuration or the way in which I filter the dataframe and join it.
Note : It runs for 5 hrs before finally giving this EOF error. It runs on small data sets fine. But  900 MB is also small.
Any help is appreciated.
